# works in python2 but not in python3 what is the error?

Tags: python

```
 return dict(map(lambda (w, m): (w, float(m)), [wmsr.strip().split('\t')[0:2] for wmsr in open(f) ]))
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: [Tuple argument unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) is not possible in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use starmap instead:

```
from itertools import starmap  

with open(f) as data:
    return dict(starmap(lambda w, m: (w, float(m)), (wmsr.strip().split('\t')[:2] for wmsr in data)))
```

Comment: I totally thought `starmap` was going to be some crazy built in for plotting relationships between all objects inside a complex map of stars in space provided as a sequence. Its not that, but I think it would be used to do soemthing like that if one were clever. Cool function!